# How do you ignore UnexpectedRollbackException in @Transactional

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I've been dealing with this exception for 2 days already and I haven't seen any answer in the internet that would resolve my problem.

I know where the exception occurs. So I have a method listening to a queue using @JmsListener. I get to successfully save data after a few exceptions due to optimist locking. What I want to do is to just ignore the exceptions because those are just warnings where I get to save the data afterwards. I first encountered ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException and StaleObjectStateException. I caught ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException. Now I am getting UnexpectedRollbackException and I couldn't ignore it.

I want to ignore UnexpectedRollbackException.

Any idea on this? I just want to ignore this exception.
This is currently my code.

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = { RuntimeException.class}, propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
@JmsListener(destination = "someQueue")
public void getMessage(String message) {
    try {
        TestEntity testEntity= testEntityQuery.findTestEntitybyId(getId(message));

        if (null != testEntity) {
               testEntity.setStatus("Ok");
               testEntityRepository.save(testEntity);
        }
    }catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException | UnexpectedRollbackException e){}
```

Comment: add the code where the exception is occurring.

Comment: @AnishB. I've added the code.

Comment: Edit your question for clarification. What exception you are getting and what exception do you want to ignore ?

Comment: @AnishB. i wrote that im getting UnexpectedRollbackException and thats what I want to ignore.

Comment: Please add the code of UnexpectedRollbackException class .

Comment: @AnishB. What do you mean? That's the method where I am getting the exception.